# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on client side only

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2016

I am facing a problem with Error Code `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` with IIS on Windows Server 2016,
I have access to the server. when checking on the server the website is shown. but on the client side, I get this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

It might seem like this question on the asp.net forum:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1210913.aspx?IIS+resets+connection+ERR_CONNECTION_RESET+

but the website is showing on the server and there is no SQL related issue.

Comment: After "the website is showing on the server", you should check the networking configuration. https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef Very likely your web browser on client side was accessing something else, than your server.

Comment: @LexLi  thanks for the comment. I also checked on another network and there was no problem with the website. The network was the problem